React Native iOS Build getting struck in XCode 15.4 in the building state
After I updated the xCode to the latest version and clicked on Archive to build my React Native iOS Application, the process got struck in building state :
AppName > Any iOS Device (arm64)               Building | 10469/10489
Versions:

Node - V 22.0

CLI - React-Native cli

Xcode version : 15.4 (15F31d)

Chip : Apple M2

macOS : Sonoma 14.5

Ram 8 GB


I tried the following steps :

Deleting the Derived Data
Restarting the Macbook
Deleting and reinstalling the node_modules
Deintegrating and reinstalling the Pods

